# Android: вывод онлайн

Tags: android, php, java, javascript, mysql

**Как можно организовать проверку на онлайн?**

1. Есть приложение на Android, работает только с сетью, без нее - нет.
2. Вся работа приложения это выборка с БД через JSON и PHP
3. На сайте есть поле, "Кто онлайн"

Нужно, что бы, пока пользователь пользуется приложением, на сайте было показано что он онлайн. 
То есть, нужно как-то с телефона с промежутком отправлять данные на сервер, о том что он в сети.

Как можно это организовать более эффективно?

У меня есть свои варианты:

**1.** Телефон каждые 10 сек (или больше) изменяет файл на сервере **"online.txt"** Добавляя себя,
а **PHP** каждые 15 сек очищает этот файл. Таким способом я думаю получать тех, кто в сети.

Но могут быть и камюшки, такие как блокировка доступа из-за подозрения в ДДоС атаке и  т.д

**2.** В БД есть таблица с пользователями, там создать ячейку **"isOnline"**
и каждые 10 сек устанавливать на определенного пользователя **"isOnline" = true**
а **PHP** каждые 15 сек ставит **false**, это все через **mysqli_query(..)**;

Таким способом, если телефон не ответит через 15 сек, значит он оффлайн.
Конечно будут задержки и т.п.

Хотелось бы спросить вашего мнения и совета.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте классическую схему с пинг-понгом. Клиент регулярно посылает серверу "пинги",  а сервер отвечает понгами. Пинги и понги - это просто маленькие пакеты заведомо известного содержания. Но если нужно посылать подобные запросы регулярно (каждые 15 секунд), то может лучше использовать постоянное подключение? Это будет экономичней с точки зрения батареи.

Работа с неким файлом "online.txt" - это плохая затея. Она может будет работать при 10-30 клиентах, но при нескольких сотнях будут проблемы. Лучше использовать обычную базу (если знаете php, то скорее всего знаете и MySQL) и в ней иметь одну таблицу, в которой в каждой строке будет id пользователя и время последней активности. При чем, одну отдельную таблицу, в которой будет всего два поля (ок, может третий - id). Если пользователя долго нет, то запись можно и удалить.

Если бы мне нужно было решать подобную задачу, я бы взял любой jabber сервер и библиотеку для  андроида. Это решит проблему с статусами сразу. Собственно сами json передавал как сообщения от пользователя "сервер", который автоматом добавляется всем в невидимый контакт лист.

Comment: А как можно организовать постоянное подключение?

Comment: с помощью php? лучше этого не делать, php не для этого. Хотя можно сделать. Ключевые слова - comet, long poll. Но лучше делать на java/c++/nodejs (то, что лучше знаете).

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд есть два варианта: пассивный и активный.

**Пассивный** это Ваш вариант **2** только я бы его немного усовершенствовал: При любом запросе клиента к серверу, писал бы в базу дату-время его обращения. Тогда вы будете знать когда клиент последний раз был активный.

**Активный** - это когда клиент каждый промежуток времени делает запрос к серверу, не зависимо от того - полезный это запрос или нет. Если уменьшить интервал таких запросов на модели веб сервиса (запрос-ответ), то количество полезного трафика резко сократится, а накладные расходы на запрос увеличится.

Есть ещё один вариант **активного** режиме - это использование сокетов (но тогда необходимо готовить для этого сервер).